# Google-analytics _trackEvent doesn't get called from linked JS file

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have the asynchronous JavaScript from Google added to my HTMl page which adds the tracker:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
    (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
    })();
```

Then in an external JS file which is definitely loaded after ga.js I have the following:

```
function activateAnalyticsTracking(href) {
    _gaq.push(['trackEvent', "test", "tester"]);
    console.log("_gaq.push called");
}
```

Now my console outputs "_gaq.push called", and I don't have any other vars on the page called _gaq, so I don't understand why, when I use a HTTP logging tool like Fiddler2 I don't see a call made to Google-analytics.

I do see a call though when I simply run _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', "test", "tester"]) from the console, so the code for that call is definitely right.

I have this function used specifically because I run other events when I link is clicked, so I'd like to use it, can anyone help me understand why this wouldn't work?

TIA

Cheers,

Blaise.

Comment: change the console.log to `console.log("_gaq.push called", _gaq);`

Answer (score 5):

Seems like you're missing one underscore in `_trackEvent`. It should look like this:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', "test", "tester"]);
```